# Change in volume of air held at the top of a tube with upper end closed and holding some liquid

Tags: pressure, air

Consider a tube both end open.dip one end in a container with water..close the top with your thumb..(make sure some air remains between your thumb and the liquid in the tube)..now take the tube out of water..
Now Does the volume of air inside the tube expands..I mean does the volume of the air held at the top increases?(top end tightly close)

Comment: Hi shashank, welcome to phys.SE.  If you want to reword [your question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108146/does-air-pressure-in-a-capped-bottle-is-different-as-that-of-open-bottle) you should edit the question directly, not create a new one.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to ask that the what happens when the tube is raised slightly(so as not to get it out of water), because if you take it "out" of water, the water falls down.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe , depends on the temperature of the outside that it's hotter or cooler. If it does expands, you'll see that some water will drop off the tube . On the contary, if the air volume reduce , there might be some air  at the end of the tube because water was vaccummed up by the reduction of air volume.

Sorry for lots of grammar mistakes , I'm from Thailand. I hope you understands